# What is wrong with my regular expression in R?

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to extract the label, name, address, city, zip, and distance from the following text:

```
A

Carl's Jr.

308 WESTWOOD PLAZA

LOS ANGELES, CA 90095-8355

0.0 mi.

B

Carl's Jr.

2727 SANTA MONICA

SANTA MONICA, CA 90404-2407

4.8 mi.

...
...
```

Here is my regular expression pattern and code, but I get a matrix of NA values.

```
p <- "(^[AZ]\\n)^(\\w+.\\w+\\s\\w+.\\s*\\w*)\\n^(\\d+\\w+\\s*\\w*\\s*\\w*)\\n^(\\w+\\s*\\w*),\\s(CA)\\s(\\d+-*\\d*)\\n^(\\d+.\\d*)\\smi."

matches <- str_match(cj, p)
```

Do I have a syntax error in my pattern?

Comment: see rule #1 in questions **not** to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `strsplit()` instead.  See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eJ9wU0/2) for an explanation of the regex used below.  Afterwards, we can figure out how many rows there will be by finding the number of single character elements.

```
s <- strsplit(x, "\n+|, | (?=[0-9]+)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
as.data.frame(matrix(s, sum(nchar(s) == 1), byrow = TRUE))
#   V1         V2                 V3           V4 V5         V6      V7
# 1  A Carl's Jr. 308 WESTWOOD PLAZA  LOS ANGELES CA 90095-8355 0.0 mi.
# 2  B Carl's Jr.  2727 SANTA MONICA SANTA MONICA CA 90404-2407 4.8 mi.
```

**Data:**

```
x <- "A\n\nCarl's Jr.\n\n308 WESTWOOD PLAZA\n\nLOS ANGELES, CA 90095-8355\n\n0.0 mi.\n\nB\n\nCarl's Jr.\n\n2727 SANTA MONICA\n\nSANTA MONICA, CA 90404-2407\n\n4.8 mi."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without regular expressions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

text =
"A

Carl's Jr.

308 WESTWOOD PLAZA

LOS ANGELES, CA 90095-8355

0.0 mi.

B

Carl's Jr.

2727 SANTA MONICA

SANTA MONICA, CA 90404-2407

4.8 mi." %>% textConnection %>% readLines

result = 
  data_frame(text = text) %>%
  filter(text != "") %>%
  mutate(type = c("ID", "name", "street_address", "city_state_zip", "distance") %>%
           rep_len(n()),
         index = ceiling((1:n())/5)) %>%
  spread(type, text) %>%
  separate(city_state_zip, c("city", "state_zip"), sep = ", " ) %>%
  separate(state_zip, c("state", "zip"), sep = " ") %>%
  separate(distance, c("distance", "unit"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(distance = as.numeric(distance))
```

Comment: How do I get the name of this data frame if I want to use it later?

Comment: See edit, I've assigned the result to a variable.